# background gradient not displaying properly with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I add a background color gradient to my web page, it works fine up until the end of the last container in my body element. After that, the gradient stops working and you see a distinct contrast between the end of the container and the rest of the empty page.

To see for yourself:

Download the default web page from layoutit.com and edit css/style.css with:

```
body {
  background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #207cca 30%, #2989d8 50%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(30%,#207cca), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 30%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 30%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 30%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#207cca 30%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

The css was generated by http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ , so I'm fairly certain it works because it seems to be the popular choice for making a gradient and it works on a non bootstrap page.

Any ideas on how to get the gradient to render through the whole page?

**Edit**
View an example at http://theshachar.com/so/

Thanks!

Comment: Set it on the `html` element as opposed to the `body` element. I think that's how bootstrap does it.

Comment: Tried it, it works worse. The gradient doesn't work in the container, but the bottom of the page still gets the starting gradient color

Comment: Interesting - Do you have an example we can look at? Perhaps a website or jsFiddle example?

Comment: I added a link in the edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your edit, the issue is that the background wasn't extending to the window height.

To solve this, simply add:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use [viewport-percentage units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) like `vw`:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

you can also set a `min-height`:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I had tried adding height: 100%; before for the body element, but it didn't work, but adding it for the html element did the trick. For the sake of understanding the fix, why was it necessary to specify it in the html element as opposed to the body? If you don't specify the height of the page, it means that it's up to the browser to figure out how to render it? Thanks

Comment: @user1549863 In this instance, the `body` element is the height of the containing contents. Since the contents didn't extend to the bottom of the page, `100%` was useless, because it already was `100%` of the contents.. By setting `100%` on the `html`, it is essentially extending it to the height of the window.